# Overlay WMTS grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wmts

I want to see the coordinates of the standard WMTS grid at various zoom levels so that I can see their "coordinates" as well as their extents. I am pretty sure that I had used a plugin for this at one point but it was a long time ago and I cannot find it again.

Whenever I try to search for help on this I get a deluge of questions about WMTS layers in general, but what I really want is just a grid with the coordinates and zoom levels that I can overlay on the canvas

Is there a plugin for this, or at least a vector dataset containing polygons with this information embedded in them?